# After read holding registers with Pymodbus connection is broken in Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pymodbus

```
import pymodbus     
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient   
from time import sleep
connection = False
data = {}
while True:
        if not connection:
            client = ModbusTcpClient(host="176.219.185.16", port="502")
            connection = client.connect()
            if connection:
                print("connected")
        if connection == True:
            if not client.is_socket_open():
                print("connection is broken")    
                connection = False
        data = client.read_holding_registers(address=150,count=10,unit=1).registers
        sleep(2)
        print(data)
```

This code is working on Windows. But i run it in raspberry pi "client.is_socket_open" is return false after read holding registers. How can i solve this? Or what is the problem in here. I dont force the client to close.

Comment: The simplest workaround is to introduce a small sleep between transaction (say 50-100ms) and that should solve the issue with pymodbus 2.5.0. Refer comment github.com/riptideio/pymodbus/issues/612#issuecomment-796758646.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few test I can replicate the problem on the windows machine, and it's related to the pymodbus version. The connection is closed with the pymodbus version 2.5.0, so just downgrade to 2.4.0 until they solve the problem.

To solve your problem check the version on both the machines with `pip3 show pymodbus`

Uninstall pymodbus from the raspberry with `pip3 uninstall pymodbus`

Install the old version with `pip3 install pymodbus==2.4.0`

---

I have found that on [github there is an existing issue reporting this error](https://github.com/riptideio/pymodbus/issues/612)

---

The creator has released a fix for [this](https://github.com/riptideio/pymodbus/issues/612#issuecomment-796803949)

Install the updated version `2.5.1rc1`

```
pip3 install --upgrade pymodbus
```

Comment: The simplest workaround is to introduce a small sleep between transaction (say 50-100ms) and that should solve the issue with pymodbus 2.5.0. Refer comment https://github.com/riptideio/pymodbus/issues/612#issuecomment-796758646.

Comment: but in the code there is alredy a sleep between the reads calls, [look at the test](https://github.com/riptideio/pymodbus/issues/612#issuecomment-796771279)

Comment: please use `pymodbus==2.5.1rc1` and see if that fixes the issue.